# How to restore a value of a variable after it was already changed?

Tags: php

I have set this code, so whenever `$_GET['start']` is a number it should output the link (continue) and the value of `$start` will increase  by `2` every time I click *continue*.

The question is when `$_GET['start']` is not a number, then the `$start` variable should not be overridden. It means it should have the default value which was `2`.

How can I do that ?

```
<?php

$number=array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'j');
$start = 2;          
$len = isset($_GET['len']) ? (int)$_GET['len'] : 2; 
$s = isset($_GET['start']) ? (int)$_GET['start'] + 2 : 4; 
$count = count($number);

foreach ($number as $value) {       
    print_r($value) ; 
}

echo '<br><br>';

if (isset($_GET['start'])) {
    $start = $_GET['start'];
}


foreach (array_slice($number, $start, $len) as $k) {
    print_r($k);
}

echo '<br><br>';                                                                      

if (is_numeric($start)) {
    if ($start <= $count) {
        echo '<a href="http://192.168.1.6/alpha.php?start=' . $s . '&len=2">continue</a>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a simple if statement, if it's empty then make the variable number 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your `if` condition as follows:

```
$start = 2;

if (!empty($_GET['start']) && is_numeric($_GET['start']) && !is_float($_GET['start'])) {
    $start = $_GET['start'];
}
```

Comment: It worked but in this way                                                                                                               
 if (isset($_GET['start']) && is_numeric($_GET['start']))
                  $start = $_GET['start'];

Comment: Adjusted the condition to include a check whether `$_GET['start']` is not a float.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if $_GET['start'] is empty, and if it is not, then replace the variable. Otherwise you can just leave it as is.

Replace

```
    if (isset($_GET['start']))
  $start = $_GET['start'];
```

With

```
if($_GET['start']!= null){
   $start = $_GET['start'];
}
```

Comment: Now it works when $_GET['start'] is empty i need it to work the same way when $_GET['start'] is equal to a letter, i mean when $_GET['start'] value is a letter it should have the Standard value  again ? thanx in advance